# extracting Stata labels in R when some variables are missing labels

Tags: r, attributes, label, r-haven

I'm working with large Stata files with variable names and labels. I need these labels to understand what each variable is.

I have been using

```
df[] %>% map_chr(~attributes(.)$label)
```

to extract the variable names and associated labels. Unfortunately some of the datasets have variables that are missing any label (see picture below).

[image]

This means that when I try the above code, I just get an error.

```
Error: Result 1 is not a length 1 atomic vector
```

Ideally I'd have a way of either calling all the missing labels "NA" or nothing, so I could get an output like this:

[image]

#

Only where variables with missing values simply don't have a label, but are still included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like purrr's strictness is getting in the way of what you want here. If you just `lapply()` (or `purrr::map()`), you'll get a list, which is perfectly nice to work with:

```
# get an example Stata dataset
webuse::webuse("auto")

# drop the label on `price`
attr(auto$price, "label") <- NULL

# get all of the labels as a list
labels <- lapply(auto, attr, "label")
```

This gives you:

```
> str(labels)
List of 12
 $ make        : chr "Make and Model"
 $ price       : NULL
 $ mpg         : chr "Mileage (mpg)"
 $ rep78       : chr "Repair Record 1978"
 $ headroom    : chr "Headroom (in.)"
 $ trunk       : chr "Trunk space (cu. ft.)"
 $ weight      : chr "Weight (lbs.)"
 $ length      : chr "Length (in.)"
 $ turn        : chr "Turn Circle (ft.) "
 $ displacement: chr "Displacement (cu. in.)"
 $ gear_ratio  : chr "Gear Ratio"
 $ foreign     : chr "Car type"
```

You can `unlist()` that if you're willing to exclude labels for variables that have no labels:

```
> unlist(labels)
                    make                      mpg                    rep78                 headroom 
        "Make and Model"          "Mileage (mpg)"     "Repair Record 1978"         "Headroom (in.)" 
                   trunk                   weight                   length                     turn 
 "Trunk space (cu. ft.)"          "Weight (lbs.)"           "Length (in.)"     "Turn Circle (ft.) " 
            displacement               gear_ratio                  foreign 
"Displacement (cu. in.)"             "Gear Ratio"               "Car type"
```

Comment: Thanks but there are so many variables (hundreds!), and so many with empty labels (who knows how many!), it isn't efficient to drop labels selectively on variables. @Weihuang Wong's solution solves both problems.

Comment: The dropping is just for a reproducible example dataset. The `lapply()` line is the only thing you need to extract labels.

Comment: My mistake - I actually like the format of the output you provided better, and so I accepted your answer. Thank you so much @Thomas!

Answer (score 1):

You can just do a pass of `map` followed by `map_chr`, i.e.

```
library(haven)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dat <- read_dta("http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/datasets/salary.dta")

attributes(dat$yr)$label <- NULL
dat %>% map_chr(~attributes(.)$label)
# Error: Result 3 is not a length 1 atomic vector

dat %>% 
  map(~attributes(.)$label) %>%
  map_chr(~ifelse(is.null(.), NA, .))
#                                  sx                                  rk 
#          "Sex (coded 1 for female)"                              "Rank" 
#                                  yr                                  dg 
#                                  NA             "Highest degree earned" 
#                                  yd                                  sl 
# "Years since highest degree earned"   "Academic year salary in dollars"
```

or equivalently

```
dat %>%
  map(~attributes(.)) %>%
  map_chr("label", .default = NA)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Weihuang Wong - your solution is great - I'm accepting @Thomas's answer because I find the format of the output easier to read. Thank you both!